# How do I access Qt resources after compiling them?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml

I am creating a build script for a PyQt6/QML app and I want to embed a bunch of SVG icons into QML. I am trying out the 'official' approach ([link to Qt website](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/resources.html)), so I created an `icons.qrc` file with the following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="6.2.4">
<qresource>
    <file>icons/info.svg</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

and then compiled it with `rcc -g python icons.qrc > icons.py`, producing a Python file that looks like this:

```
# Resource object code (Python 3)
# Created by: object code
# Created by: The Resource Compiler for Qt version 6.2.4
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PySide6 import QtCore

qt_resource_data = b"..."

qt_resource_name = b"..."

qt_resource_struct = b"..."

def qInitResources():
    QtCore.qRegisterResourceData(0x03, qt_resource_struct, qt_resource_name, qt_resource_data)

def qCleanupResources():
    QtCore.qUnregisterResourceData(0x03, qt_resource_struct, qt_resource_name, qt_resource_data)

qInitResources()
```

However, I don't know what to do next. How do I get the icons into QML?

Answer (score 1):

Import the resources in python (you don't have to do anything just import).
Then in QML you reffer to your resources like this

```
Image{id: logo
    anchors.centerIn: parent;
    width: parent.width / 1.25;
    height: width ;
    source: "qrc:/path/in/qrc/some_logo.png" 
}
```

Notes:

- the QML types you create would only be updated in the `qrc` when you generate it so the main approach would be to use `qrc` for images and stuff but for QML files you would add them to `qrc` only when deploying.
- You can generate the `qrc` XML files with the qt-designer tool, You don't need to write this file yourself.

Comment: I have tried as you said but I get the error:
`QML Image: Cannot open: qrc:/icons/info.svg`

Comment: @eslukas Can you create an MRE?

Comment: I would love to, but the project is very convoluted, so it probably would take too much time. I have now manually b64-encoded all SVG files into a file `icons.py`. At runtime, a function in the main class then decodes them and saves them to single files in the corresponding temp directory, where they are read by QML.

Comment: @eslukas I suggest you to open a new question about this and describe your workflow to create and use the `qrc`.

Comment: That's a good idea, yes, I will do with a small example whenever I get to it. Thanks!